# Unable to see the reason in "causes harm" in edit review

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

In this [edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6429652) a prior user selected "causes harm" and filled in the custom reason: *"not open source as per question"*.

Doing the review, I only saw a blue "1" next to the reason, but I'm fairly sure I didn't see this reason itself; if it did show (I can't go back and double-check), it showed in a different way than doing close votes (where you can just select it as an option).

I don't know this is a feature or a bug, but in this case, the note was useful  and would have meant I would have voted differently.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160774/166899

Comment: You should have voted to close the question, then downvoted both question and answer, then you should have pulled the pin on the grenade, then casually dropped it, then quickly walked around the nearest concrete wall.

Comment: It looks like it's also not possible to see the "causes harm" reason in a tag wiki edit review, but in this case there's no question or answer to downvote or close.